# Get database records which satisfy two date ranges and within a specific timing in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have following **[RestaurantOffer]** table.
Offers, which is valid only within two date ranges (i.e FromDate and ToDate) and  at a particular timing(FromTime,ToTime).

[image]

So I want to write a query which would give me all Offers on **current date(Today)** and the time will be more than **current Time(Today's Current Time)**. Because I don't want to get the expired Offers.

Database :

```
FromDate(date),
ToDate(date),
FromTime(time),
ToTime(time)
```

**UPDATE :**
**Note :**This Offers is not valid all 24 hours.. It is valid only FromTime-ToTime Range.
What I want :

**1st:** Give me  All today's records if today satisfies FromDate and Todate
 range.

**2nd :** After getting all the records for today , I want to get all the records which if more than or equal today's Current Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
--DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      FROMDate DATE
    , ToDate DATE
    , FromTime TIME
    , ToTime TIME
    );

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( FROMDate, ToDate, FromTime, ToTime )
VALUES  ( '2016-05-01'  -- FROMDate - date
          , '2016-06-01'  -- ToDate - date
          , '11:30:00:000'  -- FromTime - time
          , '17:30:00:000'  -- ToTime - time
          ),
        ( '2016-05-01'  -- FROMDate - date
          , '2016-06-01'  -- ToDate - date
          , '11:30:00:000'  -- FromTime - time
          , '17:30:00:000'  -- ToTime - time
          ),
        ( '2016-05-01'  -- FROMDate - date
          , '2016-06-01'  -- ToDate - date
          , '11:30:00:000'  -- FromTime - time
          , '17:30:00:000'  -- ToTime - time
          ),
        ( '2016-05-01'  -- FROMDate - date
          , '2016-06-01'  -- ToDate - date
          , '11:30:00:000'  -- FromTime - time
          , '19:30:00:000'  -- ToTime - time
          );

SELECT  FROMDate
      , ToDate
      , FromTime
      , ToTime
FROM    #temp
WHERE   ( CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) >= FROMDate
          AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) <= ToDate
        )
        AND ( CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) >= FromTime
              AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) <= ToTime
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM RestaurantOffer WHERE (GETDATE() >= FromDate AND GETDATE() <= ToDate) AND (cast(GETDATE() as datetime) >= FromTime AND cast(GETDATE() as datetime) <= ToTime);
```

Comment: this wont work if they have offers that span multiple days.  And CURDATE() is not valid on MS SQL Server

Comment: Changed the query for SQL server. Why you think it will not work for multiple days? The query checks fit into the dates range, and then checks fit in the time range.

Comment: 'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: See my commeny above :) I've changed the query for SQL server.

Comment: My reading was that the offer was valid from the [fromtime] on the [fromdate] to the [totime] on the [todate], so  if an offer expires tonight at 6pm, if you run the query last night at 7pm, it will not be returned.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a date and time field together to get a datetime if you cast them to datetime first.
So

```
SELECT * 
FROM RestaurantOffer 
WHERE Getdate() Between 
cast(FromDate as datetime) + cast(FromTime as datetime) 
and cast(ToDate as datetime)+cast(ToTime as datetime)
```

Comment: JamieA It is giving me nothing from above query. All is valid for today into that image on my question.

Comment: see this demo, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e986/4/0  it returns the record.  does your query differ from my example?  or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Ya.I have modified my question.

Comment: Actually offer is valid all the days within fromdate-todate range ... But not 24 hours(only FromTime - ToTime).